# Undo `usethis::use_XYZ()`

Tags: r, r-usethis

I'm developing a package in RStudio with `usethis`, trying to make use of best practices. Previously, I had run `usethis::use_tidy_eval()`. Now, I'm using `data.table`, and set this up by running `usethis::use_data_table()`. I get a warning,

```
Warning message:
replacing previous import ‘data.table:::=’ by ‘rlang:::=’ when loading ‘breakdown’
```

because the NAMESPACE contains the the two lines:

```
importFrom(rlang,":=")
importFrom(data.table,":=")
```

It turns out I no longer need `usethis::use_tidy_eval()`, so I'd like to revert it and in doing so get rid of the warning.

How can I undo whatever `usethis` helper functions do? Must I edit the `NAMESPACE` myself? How do I know what else was modified by `usethis::use_tidy_eval()`? What about undoing `usethis::use_pipe()`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you made a Git commit before and after running that code, there's probably not an extremely easy way. The two options I'd consider would be:

Read the source [code](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/blob/main/R/tidyverse.R#L148) of the function. This can require some hopping around to find definitions of helper functions, but `use_tidy_eval` looks like it:

1. adds `roxygen` to `Suggests` in `DESCRIPTION`
2. adds `rlang` to `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`
3. adds the template R file `tidy-eval.R`
4. asks you to run `document()` which is what actually updates the `NAMESPACE`. You can find the lines added by looking for the importFrom roxygen tags in the template file.

To undo this, you *should* just be able to delete all of the above. However,  you need to be a bit careful - e.g. if you import functions from `rlang` outside of `tidy-eval.R`, removing it from `DESCRIPTION` might prevent installation. Hopefully any such issues would be revealed by `devtools::check()` if they do happen.

The other option would be to get an older version of your package, run use_tidy_eval() and document() and then compare the changes. That will be more comprehensive and might catch things I missed above, but the same caveats about not being able to necessarily just reverse everything still apply.

Same strategy for `use_pipe()`.

Sidenote: there are probably ways to adequately qualify different uses of `:=` so that both can coexist in your package, in case that would be preferable.

Comment: Man. This is exactly the answer I didn’t want to get. I thought `usethis` made things easy, but if undoing actions requires understanding of inner workings of packages anyway, it might not be that useful. I’ll hold of on accepting this for a bit in case someone else has suggestions.

Comment: `usethis` handles the above steps for you which is already a big time save, but if you're writing a package you probably want to understand what the different parts of the package do. The point is that the actions it takes are not necessarily reversible - e.g. if you already ran `use_package("roxygen")` to add roxygen to `DESCRIPTION`, `use_tidy_eval` doesn't add it twice, and if you want to remove tidy eval then you don't want to remove things that other parts of the package still need.

Answer (score 1):

I known this is an older post but in case others come with a similar problem, I'm posting my answer anyway.

My problem was I mistakenly tried to import into my package a function (`fp_border`) from a package that it didn't exist in (`flextable`) [For reference, `fp_border()` is in the `officer`  package, not `flextable`] with the function `use this::use_import_from()`.

Not surprisingly, when I ran `devtools::check()`, I got the error:

> object 'fp_border' is not exported by 'namespace:flextable'

The quick fix was to delete the NAMESPACE file for my package, manually edit my package source code ('R/pgkname-package.R') to remove the incorrect `roxygen2` comment (`#' @importFrom flextable fp_border`), and then re-run `devtools::document()` to generate a fresh NAMESPACE file.